# T-SQL XML Value function + Case/When Is there something like a "THIS" operator in the select statement?

Tags: xml, t-sql, view, this

I have a XML column and I am creating a view. In the select statement I am using "case-when" statement with XML value function. Something like this:

```
...

Case TemlXMLColumn.value(...) AS TempResult
WHEN 1 THEN 'Google'
WHEN 2 THEN 'IE'
...
END

...
```

Then in the same select I want to do this (but it give me error):

```
...

Case TempResult
WHEN 'Google' THEN TemlXMLColumn.value(...)
ELSE ''
END

...
```

So, I am doing for now this:

```
...

Case TemlXMLColumn.value(...) --This give me the "TempResult" so am doing the same thing twice
WHEN 'Google' THEN TemlXMLColumn.value(...)
ELSE ''
END

...
```

It is not looking good to have duplicated code. Something more, I think that because of this double and even triple same XML value functions that I am calling my 'view" slows down.

Is there a other way to do this?

Comment: Can you confirm it is actually slowing down?

Comment: I can not compare it with anything else, because I have not done this in an other way, but for 22 records to displays takes me about 3-4 seconds, which is not normal for the local machine I am using.

Comment: @ Mosty Mostacho I can do this in the way above, but I want to know has anyone know if this is a good practice or there is other solution.

Comment: The fact that the whole query takes 4 seconds doesn't mean it will take more if you add more of those columns. It is not a cause -> consequence. First thing to do is to actually check if it takes more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this to avoid writing duplicated code:

```
select
  ...
  case TempResult
     when 'Google' then TempResult
     else ''
  end
  ...
from
  ...
  cross apply (
     select
        case TempXmlColumn.value(...)
           when 1 then 'Google'
           when 2 then 'IE'
           ...
        end AS TempResult
  ) x
```

I've seen a performance gain in similair situations when I only use the xml-value-function in one place, but with other built in functions like DATEADD Sql Server seems to cache the results and only execute it once even though you're using it in several places in the same query.